# query in sqlite about second row

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

i have the following query to get the second row in studentsubject table

it's work well

but I need another way give better performance than using subquery

```
 select  SbID , StID, max(mark) 
 from studentsubject
 where mark <( select max(mark) from studentsubject group by SbID)
 group by SbID   
 order by mark desc
 limit 5
```

note : i have 5 courses and i need the second highest mark for each course

```
--
-- File generated with SQLiteStudio v3.0.3 on الأربعاء نيسان 1 12:43:34 2015
--
-- Text encoding used: windows-1256
--


  PRAGMA foreign_keys = off;
      BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- Table: subject

CREATE TABLE subject (
    SubjectID   [INT IDENTITY] (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    SubjectName VARCHAR (50)          NOT NULL
);
```

---

```
INSERT INTO subject (
                        SubjectID,
                        SubjectName
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        1,
                        'C#'
                    );

INSERT INTO subject (
                        SubjectID,
                        SubjectName
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        2,
                        'C++'
                    );

INSERT INTO subject (
                        SubjectID,
                        SubjectName
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        3,
                        'JavaScript'
                    );

INSERT INTO subject (
                        SubjectID,
                        SubjectName
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        4,
                        'DataBase'
                    );

INSERT INTO subject (
                        SubjectID,
                        SubjectName
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        5,
                        'Asp.net'
                    );


-- Table: student

CREATE TABLE student (
    StudentID   [INT IDENTITY] (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    StudentName VARCHAR (50)          NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO student (
                        StudentID,
                        StudentName
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        1,
                        'Ahmad Ali'
                    );

INSERT INTO student (
                        StudentID,
                        StudentName
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        2,
                        'Khaled Ahmad'
                    );

INSERT INTO student (
                        StudentID,
                        StudentName
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        3,
                        'Mohammad Ahmad'
                    );

INSERT INTO student (
                        StudentID,
                        StudentName
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        4,
                        'Mohammad A.Sharif'
                    );

INSERT INTO student (
                        StudentID,
                        StudentName
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        5,
                        'Mahmoud Zakal'
                    );

INSERT INTO student (
                        StudentID,
                        StudentName
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        6,
                        'Morad Tamimi'
                    );

INSERT INTO student (
                        StudentID,
                        StudentName
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        7,
                        'Khalid Ahson'
                    );

INSERT INTO student (
                        StudentID,
                        StudentName
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        8,
                        'Eyad Buzzoum'
                    );

INSERT INTO student (
                        StudentID,
                        StudentName
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        9,
                        'Almeqdad a.ateeleh'
                    );

INSERT INTO student (
                        StudentID,
                        StudentName
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        10,
                        'Mohammad Abu Naser'
                    );


-- Table: studentsubject

CREATE TABLE studentsubject (
    StID INT            NOT NULL,
    SbID INT            NOT NULL,
    mark DECIMAL (2, 2) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (
        StID
    )
    REFERENCES student (StudentID),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        SbID
    )
    REFERENCES subject (SubjectID),
    PRIMARY KEY (
        StID,
        SbID
    )
);

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               1,
                               1,
                               90.5
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               1,
                               2,
                               97.5
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               1,
                               3,
                               87.5
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               1,
                               4,
                               87
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               1,
                               5,
                               83
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               2,
                               1,
                               88
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               2,
                               2,
                               80
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               2,
                               3,
                               83
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               2,
                               4,
                               81
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               2,
                               5,
                               79
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               3,
                               5,
                               79
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               3,
                               1,
                               82
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               3,
                               2,
                               72
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               3,
                               3,
                               84
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               3,
                               4,
                               87
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               4,
                               5,
                               85
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               4,
                               1,
                               83
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               4,
                               2,
                               84
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               4,
                               3,
                               88
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               4,
                               4,
                               87
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               5,
                               1,
                               95.1
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               5,
                               2,
                               92.6
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               5,
                               3,
                               90.2
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               5,
                               4,
                               82.3
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               5,
                               5,
                               89.5
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               6,
                               1,
                               85.1
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               6,
                               2,
                               82.6
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               6,
                               3,
                               92.2
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               6,
                               4,
                               96.3
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               6,
                               5,
                               85.5
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               7,
                               1,
                               85.1
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               7,
                               2,
                               87.6
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               7,
                               3,
                               75.2
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               7,
                               4,
                               92.3
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               7,
                               5,
                               84.5
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               8,
                               1,
                               79.1
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               8,
                               2,
                               77.6
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               8,
                               3,
                               75.2
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               8,
                               4,
                               72.3
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               8,
                               5,
                               84.5
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               9,
                               1,
                               88.1
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               9,
                               2,
                               86.6
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               9,
                               3,
                               84.2
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               9,
                               4,
                               92.3
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               9,
                               5,
                               83.5
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               10,
                               1,
                               83.6
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               10,
                               2,
                               82.7
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               10,
                               3,
                               85.2
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               10,
                               4,
                               88.7
                           );

INSERT INTO studentsubject (
                               StID,
                               SbID,
                               mark
                           )
                           VALUES (
                               10,
                               5,
                               80.2
                           );


    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can `OFFSET` the reqult from 2nd row and limit reqult on `4` so it will fetch `5 rows`

```
select  SbID , StID, max(mark) 
from studentsubject
group by SbID   
order by mark desc
limit 4 OFFSET 1
```

Comment: i have 5 courses so if i do this the first result will disappear

Comment: yes. coz you are setting offset to 1 so result will be from 2nd row

Comment: the result will look like this


SbID,StID , max(mark) 
4   6     96.3
1   5     95.1
3   6     92.2
5   5     89.5


so the mark for the  cousre #2 will disappear

Comment: from your first `EDIT`  it was giving the 2nd row and then upto 5th row. But now you updated your question you want every subject second highest. so it will not produce that output . let me try for that. can you share your  table_schema and dummy data for reference

Comment: do you find any solution